# Calculating $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{1^n +2^n +3^n + \cdots + n^n}{n^n}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

> **Evaluate :**
>
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{1^n +2^n +3^n + \cdots + n^n}{n^n}\right)$$

I tried using squeeze theorem, but I couldn't find the proper inequality. I also thought of using the [Stolz–Cesàro Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) but it further complicated the problem.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: $$\sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} \biggl( 1 - \frac{k}{n}\biggr)^n.$$ I think it has been asked before. Let me look.